# USB-C to HDMI adaptor does not work for my second external monitor on Ubuntu 20.04 (Razer Blade Laptop)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, nvidia, monitors, hdmi

I spent the whole day trying to make my second external monitor work for my laptop (*Razer Blade 14 - Full HD 144Hz - GeForce RTX 3060 - Black* - [Link](https://www.razer.com/gaming-laptops/Razer-Blade-14/RZ09-0427EE23-R3U1)). My primary monitor is connected via HDMI (and worked out of the box from the beginning) and I've been trying to connect the second [monitor](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08YGFKS35?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) via a Type-C to HDMI cable ([link](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B06XDMKQKJ?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) for the cable). The thing is that this configuration works for the same laptop when I use Windows (forgot to mention that I have dual boot in this laptop, Windows 11 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with a 5.13.0-52-generic kernel). Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Here I provide some outputs that I thought they could be useful based on a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402503/hdmi-to-usb-c-adaptor-does-not-works-on-ubuntu).

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   2560x1440    143.93*+ 120.00    59.95  
   3840x2160     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080    143.98*+  59.99  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 004: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor      
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:5279 IMC Networks Integrated RGB Camera
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 7392:c611 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 046d:c545 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c332 Logitech, Inc. G502 Proteus Spectrum Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1532:028c Razer USA, Ltd Razer Blade
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3a24 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If you need more info please let me know. Thanks in advance for your time!!!

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers (& used MOKutil to sign them)?

Comment: Hey @ChanganAuto, thanks for taking the time to answer to my question.
I have installed nvidia drivers (currently nvidia 530 proprietary). I had also tried 470 proprietary but didn't work either. What is MOKutil? :o